# Name of dramaturgical device where one interrupts oneself

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for an English word, if one exists, that describes a pattern of repetition—like epanalepsis, but where an actor interrupts him or herself in between repetitions. Example:

> “Send the communique, absolutely. There's a Bahrain Agreement that says... send [the communique].”
>
> — *The West Wing* ["Swiss Diplomacy"](http://www.westwingtranscripts.com/search.php?flag=getTranscript&id=76) by Eli Attie & Kevin Falls

Does any word for this exist?

Comment: I learned a new word today.

Comment: Closest thing I can think of is _tmesis_ — but that means putting one word inside another (abso-fucking-lutely) not a whole other thought between two repetitions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word you're looking for is *anacoluthon*. From Sylvae Rhetorica:

> **anacoluthon** A grammatical interruption or lack of implied sequence within a sentence.
>
> That is, beginning a sentence in a way that implies a certain logical resolution, but concluding it differently than the grammar leads one to expect. Anacoluthon can be either a grammatical fault or a stylistic virtue, depending on its use. In either case, it is an interruption or a verbal lack of symmetry. Anacolouthon is characteristic of spoken language or interior thought, and thus suggests those domains when it occurs in writing.

Not to be confused with **metanoia**, which is explicitly correcting oneself after starting out on a different tack. See [this answer on Writers](https://writers.stackexchange.com/a/2570/633).

Comment: can you give some examples of both?

Comment: @Mitch: I will give you some examples of—wait, there's the door. Oh, it was nobody—not nobody, exactly, just some salesperson.

Comment: Robusto, that was metanoia, right? But what about anacoluthon?

Comment: @Mitch: The first sentence was anacoluthon. Also, many examples of metanoia fit into the definition of anacoluthon, which is why I took pains to draw a distinction.

Comment: So obviously it's not making sense to me sense I chose the wrong one. Can you give an example of each to show the difference (and maybe one where it's both)?

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out what to say, because I don't understand how it could not be clear to you. *Anacoluthon* is ending a sentence a different way from how it started, and *metanoia* is an explicit correction of something you said, which may or not involve an anacoluthon.